# Memory allocated doesn't get freed when C# application ends

Tags: c#

I have a C++ wrapper around a Python module, which works perfectly in C++. That is there is no memory leak whatsoever. I exposed the C++ functionalities in C and used it in C# application. However, I noticed Whenever I end the C# application, the memory allocated does not get freed!

The irony is, everything is done in Python, and in C++ there is no memory allocation, it is just a series of methods which call their Python counterparts, and in Python all memory are managed by the interpreter.
The Python module basically runs an infinite loop in which a webcam feed is used and the images are processed and sent back to the clients (C#, C++). There is a `Stop` method in Python which simply sets a value which ends this loop in python so when that loop ends, effectively everything is ended and thus freed.

**Side note:**
The memory you see, is related to the model that gets loaded into the memory and that model is managed by `Pytorch` (a deeplearning framework in Python) so on the Python part we just have calls to other managed codes.

The C++, just calls these methods and I don't have any issues in Python or C++, but when it comes to C#, the allocated memory does not get freed !

In case it matters, here are my `DLLImport` statements on C# :

```cs
[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Initialize(bool showFeed);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Start(bool async);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Stop();

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetCpuAffinity(int mask);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool GetVideoFeedDbgStatus();

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetVideoFeedDbgStatus(bool status);

public delegate void CallbackDelegate(bool status, string message, IntPtr img, int rows, int cols);
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void AddCallback(IntPtr fn);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void RemoveCallback(IntPtr fn);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern  IntPtr GetCallbacks_str();
```

And this is the C# callback:

```cs
int op=0;
public void callback01(bool status, string id, IntPtr img_ptr, int rows, int cols)
{
     this.status = status;
     this.id = id;
     int[] sizes = { rows, cols };

     img = new Mat(sizes, MatType.CV_8UC3, img_ptr);
     // this is to retain the image, as the callback is so fast
     // the time c# will draw it, it will be invalidated and thus you'd get
     // distorted image. sowe make a deep copy here so we can work with images
     // at our own pace!
     img2 = new Mat();
     img.CopyTo(img2);

     //this allows to execute all interop calls under one thread
     switch (op)
     {
          case 1:
              Stop();
              //MessageBox.Show("done.");
              t.Abort();
              break;
          case 2:
              MessageBox.Show(GetVideoFeedDbgStatus().ToString());
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
      //resetting the flag
      op = 0;
}
```

How it is started:

```cs
Thread t;
private void btnRunService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmrFetchStatus.Start();
    t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        RunService();
    }));
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}

void RunService()
{
    btnInit_Click(null, null);
    Start(chkboxAsync.Checked);
}

private void btnInit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Initialize(chkbxIShowFeed.Checked);
    SetUpCallback();
    tmrFetchStatus.Enabled = true;
}
```

and this is how it ends :

```cs
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     op = 1;
}
```

and the C exposed methods are like this :

```cpp
extern "C"
{
    Core* core = nullptr;

    CORE_API int Initialize(bool showFeed)
    {
        return CreateHandle(showFeed) != nullptr ? 0 : 1;
    }

    CORE_API void Start(bool async)
    {
        core = reinterpret_cast<Core*>(GetHandle());
        core->Start(async);
    }

    CORE_API void Stop(void)
    {
        core = reinterpret_cast<Core*>(GetHandle());
        core->Stop();
    }

    CORE_API void AddCallback(CCallbackFn callback)
    {
        core->AddCallback_C_tmp(callback);
    }

    CORE_API void RemoveCallback(CCallbackFn callback)
    {
        core->RemoveCallback_C_tmp(callback);
    }

    std::string callbackLst;
    CORE_API const char* GetCallbacks_str(void)
    {
        core = reinterpret_cast<Core*>(GetHandle());
        auto results = core->GetCallbacks_C_tmp();

        // this is shared, so clear it each time. 
        callbackLst = "";
        for (auto pair : results)
        {
            callbackLst += pair.first + "\r\n";
        }

        //size_t size = callbackLst.size() * sizeof(char) + 1;
        //char* output = new char[size];
        //strcpy_s(output, size, callbackLst.c_str());

        return callbackLst.c_str();
    }

    CORE_API CCallbackFn* GetCallbacks()
    {
        core = reinterpret_cast<Core*>(GetHandle());
        auto results = core->GetCallbacks_C_tmp();
        size_t size = results.size() * sizeof(CCallbackFn) + 1;
        CCallbackFn* callback_list = new CCallbackFn[size];
        int i = 0;
        for (auto pair : results)
        {
            callback_list[i] = pair.second;
        }
        return callback_list;
    }

}
```

And in the C++ part which uses/calls the Python module:

```cpp
    this->serviceUtilsModule = py::module::import("SomeModule");
    this->cls = this->serviceUtilsModule.attr("SomeClass");
    //...
    this->startFunc = this->obj.attr("start");
    this->startFuncAsync = this->obj.attr("start_async");
    this->stopFunc = this->obj.attr("stop");
...
}
//...
CORE_API void Core::Start(bool async)
{
    try
    {
        if (async)
        {
            this->startFuncAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            this->startFunc();
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

CORE_API void Core::Stop(void)
{
    this->stopFunc();
}
```

What could be the cause here ? What should I be doing that I am not ? And here is a small demo showcasing the difference between the C++ application and the C# (The C++ doesn't have any memory issues, while in C#, I have to manually free the memory!) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRvpU.jpg

And here is a second clip, showing the C# app inside vs (more debugging info): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xJQw.jpg

The C++ app simply `start`s and then after 10 seconds calls stops and when exists all memory is freed.  In C#, however, this doesn't occur as you can see.

Comment: You need to dispose the : img = new Mat(sizes, MatType.CV_8UC3, img_ptr);  The image is probably using window allocation memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I'll give that a try and report back

Comment: @jdweng :  that didnt do anything unfortunately. apart from this, this memory is just created as the app starts (calls python module) so its definitely not from C#. I'll post another clip showcasing this from inside the vs.

Comment: Based on the screen recordings, it looks like the process is simply not exiting when the window is closed. This could be due to a variety of reasons that may not have anything to do with the interop code, such as modifying the default `Application.Run(new Form())` call in a WinForms application or starting an infinitely running foreground thread.

Comment: I believe you have a race condition.  You have a master (client) slave (server) application where c# is the master, c++ is a two port application (pass through commands and responses), and python is the slave.So you need to gracefully shutdown the application.You can't just have python stop because without c++ and c# knowing the program ended.You have to make sure the data and commands/responses get flushed as each piece terminates without any race conditions.So it should be a two step operation.c# start application and when python is finished send an end message.Then c# sends a close message.

Comment: I do start a thread in C# application. but its both marked as background and I also end it after I end the python code (that is call `Stop`) The stop routine runs inside the callback, so each time the callback is executed, it checks if it needs to call some methods, this is specified by a variable (op). first the Python is stopped and then the thread of execution is `Abort`ed. I updated the C# related code to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue seems to have been caused by terminating  the thread inside itself that is inside `callback01` which itself was run under let's say thread 2, we were trying to terminate this very thread:

```cs
...
     switch (op)
     {
          case 1:
              Stop();
              //MessageBox.Show("done.");
              t.Abort();
              break;
          case 2:
              MessageBox.Show(GetVideoFeedDbgStatus().ToString());
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
```

The Stop does stop the Python loop it seems, but it doesn't free the memory asap! as I believe is because the Python module is not unloaded, the Python object still exists and thus retains its memory. However, closing the C# app does free the memory.

Since the thread is marked as a Background, closing the app should terminate it as well.

Side note: I wonder why I didn't get any exception regarding this in C#?